# How does Docker work as far as being able to edit Apache config files and similar stuff?

Tags: docker

I am interested in getting my head around the full concept of using Docker on my server for my web clients.

Ideally I would love to create a docker with apache, PHP, MySQL, email server, DNS server, redis, memcached, imagemagick, and more and have it where I can simply launch to a clients new server and be up in minutes.

I saw this Apcache Docker here https://hub.docker.com/r/eboraas/apache-php/

It says:

> This is an Apache image including SSL and PHP5 support. In order to
>   use this image effectively, you'll need to mount:
>
> /var/www for your site content (e.g. using "-v
>   /home/jdoe/mysite/:/var/www/") /var/log/apache2, optionally, if you
>   want to store logfiles visibly outside the container /etc/ssl,
>   optionally, if you wish to use SSL with real keys

More specificlly:

> Mount /var/www for your site content

If I understand correctly this is to allow outside folder/files of websites to exist on the server outside of the Docker image so that Docker is basically just to handle the actual server software?

Some more questions:

Would things like Apache Virtualhost records for adding domains exist inside the docker image or on the server outside of it and be editable?

Answer (score 3):

> How does Docker work as far as being able to edit Apache config files
>   and similar stuff?

Pretty much however you would like it to work. :)

> If I understand correctly this is to allow outside folder/files of
>   websites to exist on the server outside of the Docker image so that
>   Docker is basically just to handle the actual server software?

Yes, that's correct.

> Would things like Apache Virtualhost records for adding domains exist
>   inside the docker image or on the server outside of it and be
>   editable?

If you want/need them to exist outside the container, then build it that way.

As you've no doubt noticed, my answers to your questions have been fairly nebulous. There's a good reason for that. Just because you're using docker doesn't mean that there is one single good way to do things. Your use case will dictate to a large degree how you want to use docker.

In my environment, we have chosen to store all configuration and all application state outside of the container. For configuration, that means that we maintain an "etc" directory on the host that contains all configuration for each type of container running on that host. Likewise, we store state (database files, etc.) on the host's filesystem instead of using data volumes. Both configuration directories and data storage locations are mounted into running containers using the `-v` runtime flag. This architecture has worked out very well for us, but it may not be what your organization needs.

There are plenty of valid use cases for using completely self-contained docker images that include configuration, along with using data volumes for application state. You'll just need to enumerate your requirements and then work out a design that fulfills your requirements.

Docker is a tool for you to use. It's up to the user to determine how they're going to use it.

Comment: Your answer was just what I needed!  Basically I do web dev work for clients and new clients often want a website so I am responsible for getting them web hosting.  I generally use Digital Ocean for hosting.  SO my goal would be to setup and configure all my dream software for the perfect server and have it in a Docker image so I can quickly deploy it to a new clients server and be up and running quickly but a still allowing me to configure there domain name and other stuff like that.......

Comment: ....continued....  The setup you use sounds like is about exactly what I would need for my use.  The idea is to be able to re-use the Docker image for each new client server.  Where you mentioned `Both configuration directories and data storage locations are mounted into running containers using the -v runtime flag.` Could you explain what you mean by ` into running containers ` are these other Docker images as I assumed this data would just live in the file-system of the root server?  Thanks for explaining it better

Comment: I now see the reference `-v` is a command for Docker and see the Docker Data Volumes` section so that helps explain better now as prior I admit I hadnt really looked over the docs too much!

Comment: I also see how multiple Docker images can be used. If I understand this correctly I am thinking that for example you could have a full LAMP stack minus the PHP in 1 base Docker image and the have a Docker with just PHP which will be included into the base image. Im thinking this would possibly allow for upgrading PHP version to require just building a new PHP Docker image instead of having to rebuild the whole LAMP Docker image.  I think i'm getting the concepts, there's just nowhere to easily confirm it which is why I posted this question here and you cleared most my questions so far!  thanks